# Meaning of "right to work" and "legally work" in job post's country of origin

Tags: applications, visa

I have seen job posts that include the terms in quotes and I would like to be enlightened on the technical definitions of these. What is meant by "*Can you legally work in the USA?*" or "*Only those who have the right to work in the UK can apply for this job.*" My understanding of these statements is that I must have the appropriate visa to let me work in these countries. (I'm asking for the common understanding, not the legal definitions).

I am currently living in the Philippines and I have no criminal record or legal obligations that would otherwise hamper me from leaving the country. Would I be considered for these jobs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title question is too broad and makes it a list question and it's arguably a legal question that's too subject to change to make sense for our Q&A format.

Comment: In regards to the USA, see 
Expatriates: [Answer for “Are you legally eligible to work in the United States?” in academic/postdoc position](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/answer-for-are-you-legally-eligible-to-work-in-the-united-states-in-academic)

Comment: You're not the only person trying to do this. I'm sure there are many government sites and postings of personal experiences on the internet.

Comment: "I can acquire the necessary documents for overseas employment" - can you? I know that a non-EEA citizen wanting to work in the UK has to have a lot more than just a clean criminal record to get a work visa.

Comment: I've edited to remove some personal information and make it clear that a legal definition is not being asked for. Recommend reopening.

Comment: @NigelHarper's comment also applies to most people who are not US citizens and wish to work in the USA.

Comment: Better suited for expatriates.stackexchange.com; these guys can answer anything that is relevant to living in a foreign country, including working there.

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding of these statements is that I must have had the
>   appropriate visa in these countries and that I can legally enter the
>   country of origin of said job posts.

That is correct.

The company is basically trying to determine ahead of time if they would have trouble actually hiring you (mostly due to visa issues), should they make you an offer.

They are trying to avoid last-minute surprises, and are signalling that they don't want to deal with any sponsorship cases.

They want to ensure that you are currently authorized to work there, have all the relevant paperwork in place, and could be ready to start working without a lengthy application and approval process that may or may not result in your being able to work.

Comment: Additionally, in some jurisdictions (eg in the UK), the company *itself* would be committing an offence by employing someone without the legal right to be and work in the UK - by asking such questions, they are also trying to avoid this.